# Ajax Displaying Message

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Have this amazing piece of code, it's working very well, but problem is that I always get new DIV with same message, how to I change it so it will appear in the same place? msgsrv.php file is just a `echo "Test Message";` but it will pull data from MySQL DB. So what I get is Test Message and then Test Message in next line, I would like to have NEW message replace OLD message.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Auction</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body{ background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:.9em; }
      .msg{ background:#aaa;padding:.2em; border-bottom:1px #000 solid}
      .old{ background-color:#246499;}
      .new{ background-color:#3B9957;}
    .error{ background-color:#992E36;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function addmsg(type, msg){
        /* Simple helper to add a div.
        type is the name of a CSS class (old/new/error).
        msg is the contents of the div */
        $("#messages").append(
            "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
        );
    }

    function waitForMsg(){
        /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
        When it complete (or errors)*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "msgsrv.php",

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
                addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                    15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages">
        <div class="msg old">
            Last Bid is:
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says, "append" will append content to element while .html() will change whole inner html of the element and replace with the content you set.

Replace

```
$("#messages").append(
        "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
    );
```

with:

```
$("#messages").html(
        "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
    );
```